# How do I make a fluid checkerboard background that contains elements inside a square in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a background that is a checkerboard, and I want to have a square contain a certain element, that is always contained there.

```
body {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%), 
    linear-gradient(135deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%);
  background-size:200px 200px; /* Must be a square */
  background-position:0 0, 100px 0, 100px -100px, 0px 100px; /* Must be half of one side of the square */
}
```

How do I make it so the checkerboard is responsive and a specific square always contains a certain element? (i.e. the center checker contains the logo, the top left square contains social links)

Thanks!

EDIT:  Specifically, I'm looking to make a fluid checkerboard so it looks good on mobile too

Comment: where are the elements ? show us a full code

Comment: There aren't elements yet, I just want to know _how_ I would set this all up.

Comment: Use CSS grid maybe?

Comment: How might I make a checkerboard with the grid?

Comment: Use nth-child selector for applying color.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that i'm trying to think desktop AND mobile, so I want to have it look nice on both.  The problem is that if I have a fixed number of divs, then it might not look the same on mobile.